# R: how do I change numerical data into text to show on my ggplot histogram, colour-code the bins and label them?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, label, histogram

I am analysing some data on condor land use and want to create a histogram showing how they use different habitats based on the "Copernicus Global Land Operations Vegetation and Energy" framework. Each habitat type is represented by a different number (10, 20, 30 etc) and there is one per recording. Imagine this habitat column, called RASTERVALU of the table to be:

```
RASTERVALUE <- c(20,30,20,40,50,126,60,20,30,20,50,40,90,20)
```

and so on...

How would I convert this numerical data into the habitat type to show on my histogram's X axis? There are thousands of recordings so I can't change it one by one in the base data.

[image: My histogram so far:]

My histogram code is as follow:

```
#histogram
landplot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(RASTERVALU)) + geom_histogram(
  col="black",
  fill = "#56B4E9",
  binwidth = 10,
  alpha = 0.8) +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "Andean condor land use") +
  labs(x="Land type classification", y="Count")+
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black"),
        axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
        text=element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

#load plot
landplot
```

I would also like to colour-code each habitat type on the histogram by the relevant colour in the Copernicus document (please demonstrate how to colour each histogram bin a certain colour) and put a label on/above each bin showing its exact number of counts.
Making the graph a bit more visually appealing than it is now would be awesome.

Comment: Is `data <- data.frame(RASTERVALU = c(20,30,20,40,50,126,60,20,30,20,50,40,90,20))` or is there some misconception here?

Answer (score 0):

Since Rastervalue is a category and not a numeric value. ie Habitat 20 is not two times as habitat 10.  I would suggest converting Rastervalue to a factor and use a bar chart.
Histogram is for a counts of a continuous variable while bar charts are for discrete categories.

```
RASTERVALUE <- c(20,30,20,40,50,126,60,20,30,20,50,40,90,20)
data <- data.frame(RASTERVALUE)
data$RASTERVALUE <-as.factor(data$RASTERVALUE)

landplot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(RASTERVALUE)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(fill=RASTERVALUE),
   alpha = 0.8) +
   theme_bw() +
   labs(title = "Andean condor land use") +
   labs(x="Land type classification", y="Count")+
   theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black"),
         axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black"),
         axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
         text=element_text(size = 12),
         axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
         axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
         plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

#load plot
landplot
```

[image]